# Flutter Search Delegate filter not working with input

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this `Search Delegate` and I'm not sure why my results do not change according to my input. It seems that the `listtile` will only appear when the textfield is focused but it's just my guess. Here's my code:

```js
final cities = ["KL", 'BANGKOK', 'LONDON', 'SEOUL', 'TOKYO'];

final sug = ['KL', 'SEOUL'];

class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
    @override
    Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
      //show
      return SizedBox();
    }

    @override
    Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
      final res = cities.where((p) => p.startsWith(query.toLowerCase())).toList();
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: res.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              tileColor: Colors.black,
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CityDetails(cityName: res[index])));
                super.showResults(context);
              },
              leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
              title: Text(res[index]),
            );
          });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten this `p.toLowerCase().`

This will solve the case

```dart
 final res = cities
        .where((p) => p.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
```